# How to enable comand button in jsf through jquery when something is wrote inside the input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, disabled-control

I have tried the following code to disable and enable the search button when something is typed inside the input text.

```
<h:inputText id="searchText" value="#{adminSearchBean.storeName}" styleClass="abc1"></h:inputText>

<h:commandButton id="goButton" value="GO" styleClass="abc"
              action="#{adminSearchBean.renderReport}"></h:commandButton>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("input.abc").attr("disabled","disabled");

 $("input.abc1").keyup(function (data) {
       disableGO();
});

function disableGO(){

    if ($("input.abc1").val() != "") {  
           $("input.abc").removeAttr("disabled"); 
       } else
           $("input.abc").attr("disabled","disabled");
};

$( "input.abc1" ).focus( function(){
    alert('focus on');
     disableGO();
});

});
</script>
```

focus and keyup is working fine, but when some text is selected which was entered earlier then still the button remains disabled. I want it to be enabled.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an event associated , like focus and keyup blur change etc. focus and keyup would work fine like anyother event if its associate with the 
textbox. In your case, i would suggest to write a js on pageload of the xhtml page, and check if any value is there in the input box. if its there make the button enable
otherwise disable. Hope this will work. If you dont want to have values which was entered earlier, use `autocomplete="off"`